# flutter_webview get html of page being displayed, How to get HTML from webview page in flutter?

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, webview

I'm trying to get the HTML from a page loaded/displayed in a `webview_flutter`.  I don't see any property/method for this in the docs (https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/webview_flutter-library.html).  I tried `evaluateJavascript()` but this is not giving me the HTML being displayed.  Not sure if there is a private method that can be used or whether this is just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

try [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter),

```
WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev/',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,//evaluateJavascript by this line, this generally controls touch events written in javascript
      ),
```

Comment: I'm already using a `WebView` with `JavascriptMode.unrestricted`.  However I cannot figure out how to get the HTML of the page that is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the html page which is being displayed
Use this plugin

```
flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2
```

Then to get html page use this method

```
val htmlBody = await webView.getHtml();
```